# Bugzilla with LDAP fails

Tags: active-directory, ldap, bugzilla

I have been trying to integrate Bugzilla with Active directory and have below configuration set.
Error: The login or password you entered is not valid.

The access log showing no error, showing 201 as status code. Any help is much appreciated.

```
1. LDAP is enabled.
2. LDAP configuration is set as below
   LDAPserver = test-domain.com
   LDAPbinddn = CN=Mansing Shinde,OU=Users,OU=test-domain,DC=test-domain,DC=com:<password>
   LDAPBaseDN = OU=Users,OU=test-domain,DC=test-domain,DC=com
   LDAPuidattribute = SamAccountName
   LDAPmailattribute = mail
```

Comment: Is this an Active Directory LDAP server? Why is that LDAPbinddn set to your personal account? Is there an option to use TLS (LDAPS)?

Comment: Yes, this is Active Directory. That user has full domain rights, I tried with Admin as well but getting the same error.

Comment: When tried with TLS, it fails. Any help, please.

Comment: @grawity- Any other approach you would like to suggest? Thank you.